# Exporting Devanagarai text from org-mode to LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have a `.tex` file with text in Devanagari script. I am able to convert to pdf using XeLaTeX outside of Emacs without any problem. However, when I try it within Emacs, the resulting pdf does not have any Devanagari text.

I am new to emacs, and am using `spacemacs 25.1`.

Here are the solutions I have already tried, but I couldn't get them to work:

- https://www.r-bloggers.com/hindidevanagari-presentations-using-orgmode-r-latex-and-beamer/
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21200/auctex-and-xetex
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926817/add-xelatex-to-the-command-list
- http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#using-xelatex-for-pdf-export

I have tried many combinations and variations of these to no success.

**How do I generate a pdf from within Emacs that shows the Devanagari script?**

**EDIT:**

Here is the minimal example which works in a `.tex` file if compiled with `xelatex` outside of `emacs` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}

मया emacs बहु रोचते।

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to write the same in org mode, desired output is not generated. Here is the content of my org mode file:

```
#+Title: Generating Devanagarai text in LaTeX?
#+LATEX_CMD: xelatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{polyglossia}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setotherlanguage{english}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}

मया emacs बहु रोचते।
```

If the org file is exported as `html`, the output has both Devanagari and English text as expected. However, no pdf output is generated when exporting as `latex`.

Comment: 1. Please provide us with a minimal tex file to work with - I don't know what Devangari script is, but if you provide a short example, I can try to compile it. 2. What happened when you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926817/add-xelatex-to-the-command-list ? That appears to be the simplest way to get XeLaTeX to work.

Comment: Thanks to @Dan for trimming the question, and to @Tyler for the inputs. I have included the minimal example in both `.tex` and `.org` formats now. I have also tried to follow the stackoverflow link which you had shared, but could not get it to work. An error message is generated saying no pdf was produced. I tried compiling with and without `(setq TeX-engine 'xetex)` command in my config.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to install Arial Unicode MS on Linux, so I can't even compile this from the command line :/

Comment: @Tyler: Really appreciate your quick response. It will be a big help. Here are two possibilities for installing the fonts (First one is most promising I think.): http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/installing-ms-arial-unicode-font-222480/ and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts

Comment: I am using it on a Mac, so it might be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, figured it out:

- Use `M-x customize-group`

  - `org-export-pdf`
  - `org-latex-to-pdf-process` (As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317810/emacsxetex-org-latex-export-to-pdf-to-create-pdfs-out-of-txt-files-saved-as-org))
  - change this option:

    - %latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f
  - to this option:

    - xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f
  - in all places!

With this set, the latex headers in the question are redundant. Just type Devanagari text, and export will work fine in LaTeX!