# Multilingual LaTeX pdf export

Tags: org-export, latex, fonts, unicode

I have an org mode file with a mix of Bengali and English text, which I got to work using Adib Hasan's solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex):

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Akaash, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla}
```

Now I also want to add Devanagari script in the same document. But anything written in Devanagari ends up as empty squares. I also found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27576/exporting-devanagarai-text-from-org-mode-to-latex), and tried mixing the two:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Akaash, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla}
#+LATEXT_HEADER: \setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
#+LATEXT_HEADER: \setotherlanguage{english}
#+LATEXT_HEADER: \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Devanagari MT}
#+LATEXT_HEADER: \newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{Devanagari MT}
```

to no avail. `sanskrit` in `\setotherlanguage` doesn't work either. In the resulting LaTeX file only the `latexbangla` line stays and the rest are discarded. How can I get all these scripts to work together?

Comment: That's a question for TeX SE: the trick is to find out how to do it in LaTeX (probably XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX are your best bets - but don't quote me on that). Once you figure that out, then exporting from Org mode will be easy I think.

Comment: Realized that I had a typo `#+LATEXT_HEADER:` should have been `#+LATEX_HEADER:`, which caused these to be ignored in the export. After that I had to explicitly put the Sanskrit text within \textsanskrit{...} following the overleaf guide on multilingual typesetting.